# Magento 2. First line of php (related to action) that exectutes after Place Order is clicked

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2, place-order

I wish to know more about the place order process.

Now I know that everything goes through index.php etc.

I'm looking for the first line of php or at least `Entity:method` that is handling  `place order`

For example if a controller would handle this action it would be `Controller:execute`

Thank you.
FWI: One Page Checkout is set.

Comment: setting up the debugger(xdebug or ZendDebugger) would give you the clearer picture of how the order is processed. I would love to see if there's some explanation in answers yet to come

Comment: Xdebugger is set yet where to put the breakpoint? I do not wish to start from index.php :(